# Moment.js - Parse Date Time Ago

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

I am saving my date like this in my mongo database:

```
Thu Oct 25 2018 17:30:03 GMT+0300 (EAT)
```

I would like to use moment.js to have in the front end like `1 hour ago` or `3 hours ago`. How would I go about this?

Comment: First, [parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the date (you may want to look into [moment's timezone extension](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)).  After parsing it, you can find a [relative time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) fairly easily.

Comment: Actually, since you have the UTC offset, you probably don't need the timezone extension.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you're using single locale try

```
moment('Thu Oct 25 2018 17:30:03 GMT+0300').fromNow(); //eg. 1 day ago, 2 hours ago etc
```

or

```
moment('Thu Oct 25 2018 17:30:03 GMT+0300').fromNow(true); //eg. 1 day, 2 hours
```

for more see [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)

and:

[image]

Comment: Had to reconvert date first before saving with moment().format()

Comment: can we change this range given by moment ?

Answer (score 6):

you can add your date and then compare with the current time:

```
const timestamp = moment(dateFromDatabase, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss GMT Z').fromNow();
```

or you can also use diff()

```
const timestamp = moment(dateFromDatabase, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss GMT Z').diff(Date.now(), 'hours');
```

you can change the measurements using `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`.

For more information, you can take a look on [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/).